# What is the difference between DeepFake and First Order Motion?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-graphics

What is the difference between DeepFake and First Order Motion?
Is it the same or not?

Comment: DeepFake is a name for an end result [in which a person in an existing image or video is replaced with someone else's likeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepfake). First Order Motion is a name for [a particular technique for image animation](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/8935-first-order-motion-model-for-image-animation.pdf) that could be used to produce deepfakes or other purposes.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE**.SE. Tag this [tag:terminology]. @plop: consider answering.